# svn read write permissions

Tags: svn, permissions

I have a question about granting rights in svn. It is possible to take permissions like that?:

[image]

In short:

Admin can all in this project, read, write delete, change but User1 and User2 can only write his changes to svn. The best will be if every user(not Admin) have permissions only to his piece of project but cant delete anything. It is possible to do? I wrote some permissions in svn files but i never had that kind of perm. Can anybody tell me in short how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot do that on a file system level. SVN supports internal permission profiles, but there is no way to differ between deleting and writing a file, since it basically is the same. You can only differ between no access, read access and full write access. This usually is not a problem, since there is no way to really _delete_ something in such a repository anyways (except on system level), since that is what a repository _is_ about: to preserve and reproduce every intermediate state. So why not allow users to "delete" something? They need to anyway when they are meant to contribute.

Comment: Ok so they cant delete, but what if i want as Admin that Users can only writes they changes, no read changes adds by different user? If you know what i mean:)

Comment: That makes no sense: the current state of a repository (or a single file inside) is the result of _all_ transactions that lead to state "now". Regardless of who did those changes. Locking down single transactions would make the information incomplete. What you _can_ do is limit access to certain _parts_ of the repository. But keep in mind that content might be relocated inside a repository and even into another repository. Taking all together: you do not want such permission schemes inside a repository, that is not what subversion (or any other RCS) is about: it is about transparency instead.